# Cherrypy Basic Authorization in header -

Tags: authentication, authorization, cherrypy

I've reviewed the documentation at http://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#authentication in order to understand how to send my API call to Cherrypy and validate an API key that I'll have in the header of the HTTP request that I'll send from my client side program.
The header will follow Basic Authorization with the header having the following example key and value
Example:   Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l

Then I want the Cherrypy function that I write to run only after some authorization has be completed.
From the client, I'll call my function like:
https:///myfunction?param1=value&param2=value&param3=value 
with the Basic Authorization header set up as seen above

and in Cherrypy I'll code the function like:

```
 @cherrypy.expose
    def myfunction(self, param1=1,param2=cat,param3=dog):
            # do my work in the function 
        return
```

Note: the function will not have a user enter any credentials.  The call will pre-populate the basic authorization header programmatically.

Can you set up the Cherrypy code example in such a way to explicitly show me how this can be achieved.  Assume a beginner with Cherrypy (e.g. did the first 5 or so tutorials only ( http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorials ).
Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cherrypy

def check_auth():
  needs_auth = cherrypy.request.config.get('auth.require', False)

  if needs_auth and not cherrypy.request.headers.get('X-HTTP-APIKEY', None) =="1234":
     raise cherrypy.HTTPError(401)



cherrypy.tools.auth = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', check_auth, priority=50)


def needsauth():
    '''A decorator that sets auth.require config
    variable.'''

    def decorate(f):
        if not hasattr(f, '_cp_config'):
            f._cp_config = dict()
        if 'auth.require' not in f._cp_config:
            f._cp_config['auth.require'] = []
        f._cp_config['auth.require'] = True
        return f

    return decorate


class main(object):
    _cp_config = {'tools.auth.on': True,}
    @cherrypy.expose
    @needsauth()
    def myfunction(self):
        print 1
        return '<html>Hi</html>'

cherrypy.quickstart(main())
```